# All paths between two nodes in Boost Graph Library

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory, boost-graph

I need to find all simple (non-cyclic) paths between two nodes in a graph. I understand how to achieve this with a modified Breadth-First-Search, and so was looking at the BFS in Boost, but I can't see how I could alter the steps of the algorithm, only the visitor.

Before I go ahead and write a new algorithm from scratch, is there a way to achieve this in BGL by using an existing algo, with or without a custom visitor?

Comment: I... think you're right and you need to write this. it's not much of a search algorithm, really. It's more like a generator.

Comment: You might consider DFS instead. I think with DFS you could keep a stack of your current path from the start node and just push and pop edges as you go. On examine_edge or back_edge put a check to see if it points to your target node.

Comment: hay, If you are interested, there is `boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths` in boost. You need may to prepare data structures accordingly.

Comment: Is that useful though in this case? I'm trying to find all simple paths, but djikstra will only give the single shortest path for a given pair of vertices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to know a little more about your graph probably. I had a "similar" problem.

This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but it is similar. This is a DFS visitor I used on a directed graph with a root to count the number of paths from the start node to all other (reachable) nodes.

This works because my graph is a DAG that is rooted. I have to reverse the graph first so that my start node is actually a sink node. The source node then becomes the root of the DAG. If I wanted the actual paths I might add a stack that tells the path history.
[image]

```
//depth first search to calculate path number, calculates the number of paths to a target
// conceptually equivalent to a topological sort.
class PathNumDFSVisitor:public boost::default_dfs_visitor{

public:
    PathNumDFSVisitor(boost::unordered_map<std::string,std::size_t>& inMap):pathNumMap(inMap){}

    template < typename Vertex, typename Graph >
    void finish_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph & g)
    {
        std::string term = g[u].termId;

        if(boost::out_degree(u,g) == 0){
            pathNumMap[term] = 1;
        }else{
            pathNumMap[term] = 0;
            //Iterate over the children of the term to add the child annotations
            typename boost::graph_traits< Graph >::out_edge_iterator ei, e_end;
            for(tie(ei, e_end) = boost::out_edges(u, g); ei != e_end; ++ei){

                Vertex v = boost::target(*ei, g);

                std::string childTermId = g[v].termId;
                pathNumMap[term] += pathNumMap[childTermId];
            }
        }
    }

    boost::unordered_map<std::string,std::size_t>& pathNumMap;
};
```

In the general case though, I would suggest calculating a shortest path and then taking each edge in turn and finding a alternate route from source to target. Now that edge could be two or more edges, which in turn would need to be relaxed and considered for alternate paths. Like Sehe said, it would be a generator, and also it could quickly explode in a general undirected graph. Maybe if we know a little more about your graph constraints we could help more.

Maybe adding a maximum path length condition could help constrain the number simple paths you are generating.

Consider this general fully connected graph.
[image]

We need to calculate all paths between `A` and `B`.

So we need all 1 edge paths + all 2 edge paths plus ...

So we need `A` - `B`, one edge.

Then all 2 edge paths.
`A` - `?` - `B`, there are 3

Then all 3 edge paths
`A` - `?` - `?` - `B`, There are 3 * 2.

And so on with 4 or more edges.

You can see as N grows we get up to N-2 * N-3 * N-4 ... and so on. This is a factorial explosion, O(N!).

These examples illustrate how different topologies can lead to very different algorithms and complexity. To get a straight/helpful answer out of SO give any details that will help.

Comment: I'm still trying to digest your answer, but my graph is undirected and cyclic.  At this stage it is unweighted (and the weights that come in later are irrelevant to this stage).

Comment: Ok, This is just an extended DFS/topological sort. It would count the number of paths from a source to all other nodes. I think in the general case, generating all undirected simple paths is O(N!). Maybe limiting the total path length will allow you to avoid such an exhaustive search.

Comment: might have a look [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/development/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.simple_paths.all_simple_paths.html). I realize this isn't really an answer. I'll leave it up in case it can help someone.

Comment: In the case of a non-fully connected graph (as is likely to be my situation), say you had two paths that did not share any edges or meet at any point other than the source and target, if you started with one path as your original and searched using this method would you ever find the other path?

Comment: @Joe that might be true using the heuristic I described starting at the shortest path. The path generation I describe in the second part would find all simple paths even for non-fully connected graphs. I just wanted to show you that it would be very costly depending on the size of your graph. Limiting the search to paths under a certain length would help considerably.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to clarify on that. I have now implemented a DFS with a max length cap, which works nicely. It is indeed quite costly, but this is being performed once in a preprocessing step on a small graph so cost isn't too much of a worry.

Comment: That's good. If you have to run a costly algorithm, might as well use BGL :).